# Spring MVC Using FOP cannot be cast to org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRendererMaker

Tags: java, spring, maven, utf-8, encode

I have issue when I work with Spring.

I have using Spring and FOP to create PDF File. But I have an issued:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFRendererMaker cannot be cast to org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRendererMaker
at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.discoverRenderers(RendererFactory.java:425)
at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.<init>(RendererFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.<init>(FopFactory.java:179)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:190)
```

This error appear when I create new Instance of FopFactory

```
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FopFactory ff = FopFactory.newInstance();

        FOUserAgent fua = ff.newFOUserAgent();
```

This is pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me check it!

Thank you!

Comment: I am also getting the same exception. Was just wondering did you get any solution?

Comment: @Abhijit, I have answered this question bellow xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have changed version of fop and this run successful

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

@Abhijit You can check this :D